# Failed to load PDF document” error message (PHP Ci3)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

Failed to open PDF with more than 2 pages
here is code which I used to download pdf file

```
 $headerct='application/pdf';
 header('Content-Type: '.$headerct);
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
 header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($filename) . "\""); 
 ob_clean();
 flush();
 readfile($filename);
```

here is the output file
[image]